# C# encrypt one set of credentials used on multiple devices

Tags: c#, encryption, hash

I have an application that uses a specific user account which is logged on using LogonUser WINAPI.
What I now need is store the credentials in a secure way (not source code (in exe)) and get it on computers.
Users cannot get to the password - I can't have them input it. Actions done by this account are sensitive and launched in the background.

I was thinking about first hashing the password with a derived key from something installer specific and replacing a few bytes of the key with a generated salt used for hashing it to obfuscate it a bit further. This initial hash would be contained in the installer which would run a helper application that would get to the password and hash it using something computer specific resulting into a different hash on each device which is not related to the initial hash.
My question is, since all of these actions are basically hard coded (using byte arrays, not strings), how safe would it be? How to really approach this?

Comment: _"how safe would it be?"_ - not at all. _"How to really approach this?"_ - hide the actual action (and user) behind a service running on a server, and issue a call to said service as the current user.

Comment: If you need the actual password how the hash should help? Hash != encryption

Comment: `How safe would it be` really depends on what you are trying to achive and what you are trying to protoect. 
Safety always needs to be prooprtional to the thing you want to protect, you dont put down a mine-field around your company if a fence is sufficient.
Haveing no idea what you want to protect id say everyone with a reasonable amount of time and an insentive to get in your system will be able to crack it. If your audience is mainly 5 year olds or there is not really an insentive to bypass the password this level of protection is probably fine.

Comment: The actions need to run on the local computer. It launches a third party application that cannot run under the system account and needs to display progress to the user as there are some reboots in between - a complicated set commands involving LogonUser, SetDACL on winsta and desktop objects etc. is needed and I do not see how these would be done remotely from the server. Securing the password is crucial as that would expose the account which is a local admin on all of the systems - tens of thousands.

Comment: Sounds like you need group policies, not an application that contains your local admin password.

Answer (score 0):

I would use windows CredentialManager for this.
Login in with that user, open the CredentialManager and set the user/password pair, then access these values like here:
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/CredRead%20.html

or with a wrapper like here:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/CredentialManagement

The credential manager encrypts internaly the values with DPAPI (key based on your account key).